# How to Capture Only Surnames from a Regex Pattern?

Tags: regex, perl

Team

I have written a Perl program to validate the accuracy of formatting (punctuation and the like) of surnames, forenames, and years.
If a particular entry doesn't follow a specified pattern, that entry is highlighted to be fixed.

For example, my input file has lines of similar text:

```
<bibliomixed id="bkrmbib5">Abdo, C., Afif-Abdo, J., Otani, F., &amp; Machado, A. (2008). Sexual satisfaction among patients with erectile dysfunction treated with counseling, sildenafil, or both. <emphasis>Journal of Sexual Medicine</emphasis>, <emphasis>5</emphasis>, 1720–1726.</bibliomixed>
```

My programs works just fine, that is, if any entry doesn't follow the pattern, the script generates an error. The above input text doesn't generate any error. But the one below is an example of an error because **Rose A. J.** is missing a comma after **Rose**:

```
NOT FOUND: <bibliomixed id="bkrmbib120">Asher, S. R., &amp; Rose A. J. (1997). Promoting children’s social-emotional adjustment with peers. In P. Salovey &amp; D. Sluyter, (Eds). <emphasis>Emotional development and emotional intelligence: Educational implications.</emphasis> New York: Basic Books.</bibliomixed>
```

From my regex search pattern, is it possible to capture all the surnames and the year, so I can generate a text prefixed to each line as shown below?

```
<BIB>Abdo, Afif-Abdo, Otani, Machado, 2008</BIB><bibliomixed id="bkrmbib5">Abdo, C., Afif-Abdo, J., Otani, F., &amp; Machado, A. (2008). Sexual satisfaction among patients with erectile dysfunction treated with counseling, sildenafil, or both. <emphasis>Journal of Sexual Medicine</emphasis>, <emphasis>5</emphasis>, 1720–1726.</bibliomixed>
```

My regex search script is as follows:

```
while(<$INPUT_REF_XML_FH>){
    $line_count += 1;
    chomp;
    if(/

    # bibliomixed XML ID tag and attribute----<START>
    <bibliomixed
    \s+
    id=".*?">
    # bibliomixed XML ID tag and attribute----<END>

    # --------2 OR MORE AUTHOR GROUP--------<START>
    (?:
    (?:
    # pattern for surname----<START>
    (?:(?:[\w\x{2019}|\x{0027}]+\s)+)? # surnames with spaces
    (?:(?:[\w\x{2019}|\x{0027}]+-)+)?  # surnames with hyphens
    (?:[A-Z](?:\x{2019}|\x{0027}))?  # surnames with closing single quote or apostrophe O’Leary
    (?:St\.\s)? # pattern for St.
    (?:\w+-\w+\s)?# pattern for McGillicuddy-De Lisi
    (?:[\w\x{2019}|\x{0027}]+)  # final surname pattern----REQUIRED
    # pattern for surname----<END>
    ,\s
    # pattern for forename----<START>
    (?:
    (?:(?:[A-Z]\.\s)+)?  #initials with periods
    (?:[A-Z]\.-)? #initials with hyphens and periods <<Y.-C. L.>>
    (?:(?:[A-Z]\.\s)+)?  #initials with periods
    [A-Z]\. #----REQUIRED
    # pattern for titles....<START>
    (?:,\s(?:Jr\.|Sr\.|II|III|IV))?
    # pattern for titles....<END>
    )
    # pattern for forename----<END>
    ,\s)+
    #---------------FINAL AUTHOR GROUP SEPATOR----<START>
    &amp;\s
    #---------------FINAL AUTHOR GROUP SEPATOR----<END>

    # --------2 OR MORE AUTHOR GROUP--------<END>
    )? 

    # --------LAST AUTHOR GROUP--------<START>

    # pattern for surname----<START>
    (?:(?:[\w\x{2019}|\x{0027}]+\s)+)? # surnames with spaces
    (?:(?:[\w\x{2019}|\x{0027}]+-)+)?  # surnames with hyphens
    (?:[A-Z](?:\x{2019}|\x{0027}))?  # surnames with closing single quote or apostrophe O’Leary
    (?:St\.\s)? # pattern for St.
    (?:\w+-\w+\s)?# pattern for McGillicuddy-De Lisi
    (?:[\w\x{2019}|\x{0027}]+)  # final surname pattern----REQUIRED
    # pattern for surname----<END>
    ,\s
    # pattern for forename----<START>
    (?:
    (?:(?:[A-Z]\.\s)+)?  #initials with periods
    (?:[A-Z]\.-)? #initials with hyphens and periods <<Y.-C. L.>>
    (?:(?:[A-Z]\.\s)+)?  #initials with periods
    [A-Z]\. #----REQUIRED
    # pattern for titles....<START>
    (?:,\s(?:Jr\.|Sr\.|II|III|IV))?
    # pattern for titles....<END>
    )
    # pattern for forename----<END>

    (?: # pattern for editor notation----<START>
    \s\(Ed(?:s)?\.\)\.
    )? # pattern for editor notation----<END>

    # --------LAST AUTHOR GROUP--------<END>
    \s
    \(
    # pattern for a year----<START>
    (?:[A-Za-z]+,\s)? # July, 1999
    (?:[A-Za-z]+\s)? # July 1999
    (?:[0-9]{4}\/)? # 1999\/2000
    (?:\w+\s\d+,\s)?# August 18, 2003
    (?:[0-9]{4}|in\spress|manuscript\sin\spreparation) # (1999) (in press) (manuscript in preparation)----REQUIRED
    (?:[A-Za-z])? # 1999a
    (?:,\s[A-Za-z]+\s[0-9]+)? # 1999, July 2
    (?:,\s[A-Za-z]+\s[0-9]+\x{2013}[0-9]+)? # 2002, June 19–25
    (?:,\s[A-Za-z]+)? # 1999, Spring
    (?:,\s[A-Za-z]+\/[A-Za-z]+)? # 1999, Spring\/Winter
    (?:,\s[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+)? # 2003, Mid-Winter
    (?:,\s[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+)? # 2007, Anniversary Issue
    # pattern for a year----<END>
    \)\.
    /six){
        print $FOUND_REPORT_FH "$line_count\tFOUND: $&\n";
        $found_count += 1;
    } else{
        print $ERROR_REPORT_FH "$line_count\tNOT FOUND: $_\n";
        $not_found_count += 1;
    }
```

Thanks for your help,

Prem

Answer (score 0):

Alter this bit

```
# pattern for surname----<END>
    ,?\s
```

This now means an optional , followed by white space.  If the Persons surname is "Bunga Bunga" it won't work

Comment: I am sorry if I confused you. The script is supposed to catch "<bibliomixed id="bkrmbib120">Asher, S. R., &amp; Rose A. J. (1997)." as an error, and it did! That's not the issue I am facing. I would like to know how I can add "<bib>Surname1, Surname2, Surnam3, 2013<bib>" if the input line were, for example, "<bibliomixed id="bkrmbib5">Abdo, C., Afif-Abdo, J., Otani, F., &amp; Machado, A. (2008)." That is capture all surnames and the year.

Answer (score 0):

All of your subpatterns are non-capturing groups, starting with `(?:`. This reduces compilation times by a number of factors, one of which being that the subpattern is not captured.

To capture a pattern you merely need to place parenthesis around the part you require to capture. So you could remove the non-capturing assertion `?:` or place parens `()` where you need them. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings

I'm not sure but, from your code I think you may be attempting to use lookahead assertions as, for example, you test for surnames with spaces, if none then test for surnames with hyphens. This will not start from the same point every time, it will either match the first example or not, then move forward to test the next position with the second surname pattern, whether the regex will then test the second name for the first subpattern is what I am unsure of. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;


my $line = '123 456 7antelope89';

$line =~ /^(\d+\s\d+\s)?(\d+\w+\d+)?/;

my ($ay,$be) = ($1 ? $1:'nocapture ', $2 ? $2:'nocapture ');

print 'a: ',$ay,'b: ',$be,$/;

undef for ($ay,$be,$1,$2);


$line = '123 456 7bealzelope89';

$line =~ /(?:\d+\s\d+\s)?(?:\d+\w+\d+)?/;

($ay,$be) = ($1 ? $1:'nocapture ', $2 ? $2:'nocapture ');

print 'a: ',$ay,'b: ',$be,$/;

undef for ($ay,$be,$1,$2);


$line = '123 456 7canteloupe89';

$line =~ /((?:\d+\s\d+\s))?(?:\d+(\w+)\d+)?/;

($ay,$be) = ($1 ? $1:'nocapture ', $2 ? $2:'nocapture ');

print 'a: ',$ay,'b: ',$be,$/;

undef for ($ay,$be,$1,$2);

exit 0;
```

For capturing the whole pattern the first pattern of the third example does not make sense, as this tells the regex to not capture the pattern group while also capturing the pattern group. Where this is useful is in the second pattern which is a fine grained pattern capture, in that the pattern captured is part of a non-capturing group.

```
a: 123 456 b: 7antelope89
a: nocapture b: nocapture 
a: 123 456 b: canteloupe
```

One little nitpic

```
  id=".*?"
```

may be better as

```
  id="\w*?"
```

id names requiring to be _alphanumeric iirc.